# How does one find the amount of memory remaining to allocate objects?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

How do you tell how much memory the JVM has left to use?

I know Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() would be the way to go, but it does not seem to return a reasonable value. For example when I run my main method, I print the free memory and get 78904576 bytes, which is only 75 megabytes. Since I have maxMemory set at 2 gigabytes that seems unreasonable.

Honestly, I just want to know how close I am to running out of memory, so an answer that provides an alternate mechanism for that would also be acceptable.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what you exactly need this for. If you care about memory consumption and fear OOM-Errors, you can define certain (large) objects as `SoftReference`, whose memory space will be freed, if the application runs out of memory - so ideal solution for cached values or data.

Comment: An algorithm that has a good estimate of the amount of remaining memory (and a good function to convert that value into relevant parameters) can tune itself based on the info: i.e. make time versus space tradeoffs based on knowing the available space.

Comment: @RomanVottner I am messing around with threading and I wanted to write an ExecutorService that only starts new threads when a certain amount of memory is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the formula

```
long availableMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory())
```

freeMemory() shows free memory only from currently allocated memory, to get all available memory we must also include memory which has not been allocated yet.

Another solution

```
    MemoryUsage mu = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage();
    long availableMemory = mu.getMax() - mu.getUsed();
```

Comment: @Gregor Why not [figure it out yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) - you will gain more experience and knowledge than just copy/pasting others solution

Comment: @RomanVottner Why do we need a Q&A site if everyone can just figure it out for himself. People sometimes come to SO for cut and paste solutions.

Comment: @Kaz nothing against quick copy/paste solutions, but then they should at least be able to understand what they are copying

Comment: @RomanVottner so in response to me asking for why this works, which I did because I don't like to copy paste code I don't understand, you say "you will gain more experience and knowledge than just copy/pasting". Huh? That doesn't make sense to me. My confusion is now accurately addressed, I now know that freeMemory only shows free memory from allocated memory.

Comment: @Gregor Maybe I used the wrong words and I should have said by looking up what these methods do yourself instead of `just copy/pasting` - though, the result is the same - you gain experience and knowledge. At least I don't see a big clash there. Either way, you have your working solution which you furthermore do understand and Evgeniy has an upvoted and accepted answer - I call that a win-win situation

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to monitor the JVM memory you are probably better off using a profiling tool like YourKit or JProfilier.

Comment: I would rather not use an external tool. I just want to be able to quickly check how much memory is left, programmatically..